# Why are my LaunchDaemons disappearing after reboot in Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: catalina, launchd, plist, daemons

I've got a group of `launchds` which I've been using across a dozen OS versions in Mac. These do various things (such as shut off TimeMachine for parts of the day when the system is most heavily used, to prevent performance lag, etc).

I just upgraded to Catalina (yeah, I prefer to let everybody else play pioneer and get the arrows).

But when I run `launchctl` and load these, they load, then show running.
BUT, after a few days they disappear.

From what I can tell, they don't survive a reboot.

Now I have already disabled SIP (`csrutil status`), which allowed me to actually run `launchctl` and load the daemons.

But why aren't the plists STAYING loaded and continuing to operate?

Comment: Are you installing them in /Library/LaunchDaemons, or loading them from somewhere else?

Comment: Since this problem is not usual, we need a bit more information. As well as where the plists are, might be good to know the `launchctl` commands used and the content of a least one problematic plist.

Comment: If you were to update to a modern version on macOS (and APFS), you would find that Time Machine is very unobstrusive.